# How are pixels drawn at the lowest level

Tags: c++, assembly, gdi

I can use setpixel (GDI) to set any pixel on the screen a colour.

So how would I reproduce Setpixel in in the lowest assembly level. What actually is happening that triggers the instructions that say, ok sens a byte a position x in the framebuffer.

Comment: This depends entirely on the hardware (and the interface to that hardware). For modern hardware, it's very complex. You might want to look at some old hardware documentation ([maybe for the NES?](http://nesdev.com/NESDoc.pdf)) that has a relatively simple graphics system. Although they were typically designed for very specific applications, this will at least give you an idea for how it *could* be done.

Comment: Today, pixels are drawn by the graphic card, not by the CPU. Take a look at OpenGL and shader programming. That's where the rabbit hole goes today.

Comment: Today, pictures are not drawn by single pixels anyway, all operations are accelerated by the GPU, which has it's own fast methods and pipelines to draw 2D and project 3D objects.

Comment: @OP Don't use SetPixel at all. Here is what happens.

SetPixel grabs all pixels for an entire dc/window/screen and stores it in a buffer. It sets the colour of that pixel and then blits/paints the entire thing back to the screen.

Now imagine you have a 1000x1000 bitmap, it is 1 call per pixel; that is 1m calls to SetPixel and that's 1mx1m = one trillion pixels being copied alone. It then has to paint all of that back to the screen.

A faster way would be to grab the pixels from the screen all at once, colour as many pixels as you want and blit/paint them all back to the screen.

Comment: See here for better examples: http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/36376-getpixel-is-slow/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to recreate setpixel you need to know how your graphics hardware works. Most hardware manufacutrres follow at least the VESA standard, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions). This standard specifies that you can set the display mode using interrupt 0x10.

Once the display mode is set the memory region displayed is defined in the standard and you can simply write directly to display memory.

Advanced graphics hardware deviates from the standard (because it only covers the basics). So the above does not work for advanced features. You'll have to resort to the gpu documentation.

Answer (score 1):

setpixel most probably just calculates address of given pixel using formula:

pixel = (frame_start + y * frame_width) + x

then it simply *pixel = COLOR

You can actually use CreateDIBSection to create your own buffers and associate it with DeviceContext, then you can modify pixels at the low level using formula as above. This is usefull if you have your own graphics library like AGG.

Learning about GDI I like to look into WINE source code, here you can see how complicated it actually is (dibdrv_SetPixel):

http://fossies.org/dox/wine-1.6.1/gdi32_2dibdrv_2graphics_8c_source.html

it must take into account also clipping regions, and also different pixel sizes and probably other features. Also it is possible that some drivers might somehow accelerate this in hardware, but I have not heard of it.

Comment: With Aero off this might actually draw into the real framebuffer but with Aero on (Desktop Composition Manager) it is really only updating a bitmap in memory, which is later drawn to the real framebuffer using the GPU (per the comments on the original question). These days the application framebuffer is an abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

The "how" is always depends on "what", what I mean is that for different setups there are different methods, different systems different methods, what is common is that they are usually not allowing you to do it directly i.e. write to a memory address that will be displayed.

Some devices with dedicated setup may allow you to do that ( like some consoles do as far as I know ) but there you will have to do some locking or other utility work to make it work as it should.

Since in modern PCs Graphics Accelerators are fused into the video cards ( one counter example is the Voodoo 1 which needed a video card in order to operate, since it was just a 3D accelerator ) the GPU usually holds the memory that it will draw from the framebuffer in it's own memory making it inaccessible from the outside.

So generally you would say here is a memory address "download" the data into your own GPU memory and show it on screen, and this is where the desktop composition comes in. Since video cards suffer from this transfer all the time it is in fact faster to send the data required to draw and let the GPU do the drawing. So Aero is just a visual but as far as I know the desktop compositor works regardless of Aero making the drawing GPU dependent.

So technically low level functions such as SetPixel are software since Windows7 because of the things I mentioned above so solely because you just cant access the memory directly. So what I think it probably does is that for every HDC there is a bitmap and when you use the set pixel you simply set a pixel in that bitmap that is later sent to the GPU for display.

In case of DOS or other old tech. it is probably just an emulation in the same way it is done for GDI.

So in the light of these,

> So how would I reproduce Setpixel in in the lowest assembly level.

it is just probably a copy to a memory location, but windows integrates the window surfaces and it's frambuffer that you will never get direct access. One way to emulate what it does is to make a bitmap get it memory pointer and simple set the pixel manually then tell windows to show this bitmap on screen.

> What actually is happening that triggers the instructions that say, ok sens a byte a position x in the framebuffer.

Like I said before it really depends on the environment what is done at the moment you make this call, and the code that needs to be executed comes from different places , some are done by Microsoft some are done by the GPU's manufacturer and these all together produce the result that pixel you see on your screen.

Answer (score 0):

For to set a pixel to the framebuffer using a videomode with 32 bit color we need the address of the pixel and the color of the pixel.
With the address and the color we can simple use a move instruction to set the color to the framebuffer.

Sample with using the EDI-Register as a 32bit addressregister(default segmentregister is DS) for to address the framebuffer with the move instruction.
x86 intel syntax:

```
 mov edi, Framebuffer   ; load the address(upper left corner) into the EDI-Register
 mov DWORD [edi], Color ; write the color to the address of DS:EDI
```

The first instruction load the EDI-Register with the address of the framebuffer and the second instruction write the color to the framebuffer.

Hint for to calculate the address of a pixel inside of the frambuffer:
Some Videomodes are using maybe a lorger scanline with more bytes for the horizontal resolution, with a part outside of the visible view.

Dirk